# PHP WMV file upload failed

Tags: php

I'm doing a test with PHP file upload but seems like my script isn't allowing me to upload WMV.

Here is the PHP script that I have

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Here is the HTML script

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

When I try other formats like jpg, mov it works just fine.
Is there a special setup I need to do for wmv?
I'm using XAMMP on mac

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I am having the same problem.  I have set the upload size to 256MB and still cannot upload certain files.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini that your POST max size and maximum file upload size are at least as large as the file size of your .wmv file (your HTML instruction is client-side only). The type of file itself should make no difference. (Restart your web server after changing your php.ini file and use `<?php phpinfo(); >` to find out where your php.ini file is being loaded from.)

Comment: Thanks Ian, yes those are set right. Also the wmv is only 1 MB, while I can successfully upload an mov that is 21 MB.

Comment: I guess if you renamed it to somefile.mpg it should still fail. Are there any odd characters in your filename? : / & ?. Also check you don't have a file already uploaded there with the same name (if possible, @unlink(filename) first).